# JavaScript array access with commas

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

Why does the following not throw any syntax errors?

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    b = a[2, 1, 0, 1];

console.log(b);
```

See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2eng5typ/

Comment: Woops. I searched for an answer to this before asking, but I wasn't able to find that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.
The , is a comma operator in the above case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

2.
The first [] defines an array.

3.
The a[...] dereference the ... element from the array, where ... is the last element which is 1

4.
So basically this happens:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = a[1];
console.log(b);
```

which is the same as:

```
var b = 2;
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Thank you. I never knew about this operator. I don't think I'll ever use it.

Comment: You'll see this in the output of a lot of minifiers.